# Getting a Axis 1.1 client talk to an Axis2 service

Tags: java, web-services, client, apache-axis, axis

Is it possible to have an Axis 1.1 client talk to an Axis2 web service endpoint?  From my understanding, web services work by passing XML SOAP messages back and forth using the schema specified by the service's WSDL, but I'm unsure as to whether or not these versions of Axis utilize different versions of the web service specification that would stop them from talking.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, using Axis 1.1 to communicate with an Axis2 web service works just fine.  I generated the stubs using Axis 1.1, created a Client class, and tested.  Axis 1.1's API doesn't offer some of the same functionality that my previous Axis 1.4 allows, specifically in the ParameterDesc class, where you can specify if web service method parameters are nillable or their minOccurs, but my calls seemed to work just fine.

All in all, it can be done with (what appear to be) basic WSDL definitions, however, I'm unsure as to whether or not Axis2 utilizes new functionality that Axis 1.1 cannot accommodate due to Axis 1.1's aged API...

Oh, and one last note, I needed to use SOAP 1.1 stubs for my request.  I'm not 100% sure why since my responses were coming back as SOAP 1.2, but there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

In general your understanding is correct,i.e. that if a client adheres to the WSDL description it should be able to contact the web service.
But Axis1 and Axis2 use by default different encodings which are not compatible.
Axis1 uses RPC (which is obsolete) and Axis2 uses doc/lit.
So the oposite of what you ask i.e. an Axis2 client communicating with an Axis1 server will not work.
For the reverse (and what you ask in the post) I am not really sure.
Did you try to generate the stubs using the WSDL?
Did you get any errors? If you got no errors in stub creation, I believe you could give it a try.