# Using axis 1.4 on server side and axis 2.0 on client side

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java, axis

I have a wsdl and xsd to create a web service. I am planning to use axis's wsdltojava to generate the stub and skeleton. The server side Axis is on 1.4 version and client side Axis is on version 2.0. In the initially phases of the project, we created a dummy (with limited test data) web service client and server code using axis 2. So far so good. When it came to putting the real one we realized that server side application server is axis 1.4. It is hosting other web services as well. So, we have 2 options here to implement the new web service.

1) Upgrade the server side Axis from 1.4 to 2.0. Upgrade other web services to 2.0. and generate my new web service's client and server stubs using axis2 wsdltoJava.

2) Use Axis 1.4 wsdltoJava and generate server side stub and use Axis 2.0 wsdltoJava and generate client side stub.

Any suggestions/recommendations going with either of the approaches? Do you see any compatibility issues with the second approach? Got to decide one way the other. A quick response is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use second approach. Server version and client version is two different thing. You can use C# if you like in client side or other languages or frameworks. It does not matter. So create your web services as you like.

But be careful. Try not to use a WSDL which is RPC/encoded. RPC/encoded web services are not [WS-I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Interoperability) compatible. Because of that some of the frameworks ilke JAX-WS does not support it.

Comment: Thanks. I found the below links on web warning about potential incompatibility issues.                                           1) step 4 in http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-webservices-axis2-vs-axis1

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285698/getting-a-axis-1-1-client-talk-to-an-axis2-service

Comment: Please advice if I can use Axis 1.4 to generate stub on the server side.